# Displaying array properties for custom PSObjects

Tags: powershell

I'm pretty new to PowerShell, so to learn the ropes better, I'm working on a Powershell function to return some basic overview information on computers in our network. I've gotten just about everything that I'm looking for, but I don't know how to display all results for arrays returned by the [WMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) queries for things like hard disks or [MAC addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address).

For example, right now I'm using the WMI query "DHCPEnabled = TRUE" to detect active [NICs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller) and retrieve their MAC addresses - but on a laptop, it's theoretically possible that query could return both a wired and wireless NIC.

The output of this command would then display the custom [PSObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psobject%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that I create, but in the resultant PSObject, the property `MACAddress` will display blank. The results are there, and I could get to them via the pipeline or a [Select-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx), but I don't know how to save them for a report or otherwise "prettify" them.

Here's the working function I have now, which makes an awful assumption that the first result returned is the only one I care about. Again, in this example, this is mostly a concern for hard disks and for MAC addresses, but I'd like to understand the concept behind it for future reference.

```
Function Get-PCInfo
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
               Position = 0,
               ValueFromPipeline = $true,
               ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [Alias("CName")]
    [string[]] $ComputerName
    )

    foreach($cName in $ComputerName)
    {
        Write-Verbose "Testing connection to $cName"
        If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $cName -BufferSize 16 -Quiet)
        {
            Write-Verbose "Connection successful."
            Write-Verbose "Obtaining WMI objects from $cName"
            $cs = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $cName
            $csp = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystemProduct -ComputerName $cName
            $os = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $cName
            $bios = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_BIOS -ComputerName $cName
            $cpu = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Processor -ComputerName $cName
            $hdd = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter 'DeviceID = "C:"' -ComputerName $cName
            $network = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'DHCPEnabled = True' -ComputerName $cName

            if ($hdd -is [System.array])
            {
                Write-Verbose "Multiple hard drives detected; using first result"
                $hddResult = $hdd[0]
            } else {
                Write-Verbose "Single hard drive detected"
                $hddResult = $hdd
            }

            if ($network -is [System.array])
            {
                Write-Verbose "Multiple network cards detected; using first result"
                $networkResult = $network[0]
            } else {
                Write-Verbose "Single network card detected"
                $networkResult = $network
            }

            Write-Verbose "Creating output table"
            $props = @{'Name' = $cs.Name;
                       'OSVersion' = $os.Version;
                       'ServicePack' = $os.ServicePackMajorVersion;
                       'HardDiskSize' = $hddResult.Size;
                       'SerialNumber' = $bios.serialNumber;
                       'Model' = $cs.Model;
                       'Manufacturer' = $cs.Manufacturer;
                       'Processor' = $cpu.Name;
                       'RAM' = $cs.TotalPhysicalMemory;
                       'MACAddress' = $networkResult.MACAddress}

            Write-Verbose "Creating output object from table"
            $result = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props

            Write-Verbose "Outputting result"
            $resultArray += @($result)
        } else {
            Write-Verbose "Connection failure"
            $resultArray += @($null)
        }
    }

    Write-Output $resultArray
}
```

Here's an example run, for some more clarity. The data is fake, but this is the format of the result:

PS> Get-PCInfo localhost

```
SerialNumber : 12345
MACAddress   :
RAM          : 4203204608
Manufacturer : Computers, Inc.
Processor    : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz
HardDiskSize : 500105736192
OSVersion    : 6.2.9200
Name         : PC1
Model:       : Super Awesome Computer
ServicePack  : 0
```

I'd like to send this to ConvertTo-HTML or something to make a nice-looking report, but because `MACAddress` is blank, I can't make anything nice out of it. What I'd like to see is something like this:

```
SerialNumber   : 12345
MACAddress[0]  : 00-11-22-33-44-55
MACAddress[1]  : 88-99-AA-BB-CC-DD
...
HardDiskSize[0]: 500105736192
HardDiskSize[1]: 500105736192
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand? It depends on how you want them to output. You can do it in many ways. An example for HDDs and MAC addresses:

```
....
'HardDiskSize' = ($hdd | % { "HDD $($_.DeviceID) - $($_.Size)" }) -join "`n"
....
'MACAddress' = ($networkResult | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MACAddress) -join "`n"
}
```

You can try this (untested). Copy and paste the edited parts back:

```
$hdd = @(Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter 'DeviceID = "C:"' -ComputerName $cName)
$network = @(Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'DHCPEnabled = True' -ComputerName $cName)

$props = @{'Name' = $cs.Name;
            'OSVersion' = $os.Version;
            'ServicePack' = $os.ServicePackMajorVersion;
            'SerialNumber' = $bios.serialNumber;
            'Model' = $cs.Model;
            'Manufacturer' = $cs.Manufacturer;
            'Processor' = $cpu.Name;
            'RAM' = $cs.TotalPhysicalMemory;

Write-Verbose "Creating output object from table"
$result = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props

# Add MAC addresses
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $network.Count; $i++) {
    Add-Member -InputObject $result -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "MACAddress[$i]" -Value $network[$i].MACAddress
}

# Add HDDs
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $hdd.Count; $i++) {
    Add-Member -InputObject $result -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "HardDiskSize[$i]" -Value $hdd[$i].Size
}
```

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.  I edited the post to add an example of what I'm looking for.  I like the MACAddress example you mentioned; I'll have to research the -ExpandProperty flag of Select-Object.  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you!  So Add-Member can be used to add properties to PSObjects...interesting.  That's exactly what I was looking for.